# Access multiple nested TypeScript type generated from GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, graphql, react-query

I need to access only the "departments" type in this large type generated from GraphQL:

```
export type GetCompanyChartQuery = (
  { __typename?: 'Query' }
  & { generateOrgChart?: Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'DepartmentNode' }
    & Pick<DepartmentNode, 'name'>
    & { manager?: Maybe<(
      { __typename?: 'EmployeeNode' }
      & Pick<EmployeeNode, 'name' | 'mobilePhone'>
    )>, departments?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<(
      { __typename?: 'DepartmentNode' }
      & Pick<DepartmentNode, 'name' | 'depth'>
      & { manager?: Maybe<(
        { __typename?: 'EmployeeNode' }
        & Pick<EmployeeNode, 'name'>
      )>, employees?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<(
        { __typename?: 'EmployeeNode' }
        & Pick<EmployeeNode, 'imageUrl' | 'mobilePhone' | 'name' | 'position' | 'title' | 'depth'>
      )>>>, departments?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<(
        { __typename?: 'DepartmentNode' }
        & Pick<DepartmentNode, 'name' | 'depth'>
        & { manager?: Maybe<(
          { __typename?: 'EmployeeNode' }
          & Pick<EmployeeNode, 'name'>
        )>, employees?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<(
          { __typename?: 'EmployeeNode' }
          & Pick<EmployeeNode, 'imageUrl' | 'mobilePhone' | 'name' | 'position' | 'title' | 'depth'>
        )>>> }
      )>>> }
    )>>> }
  )> }
);
```

I cannot find a way around this. Pick<GetCompanyChartQuery, 'subType'> or GetCompanyChartQuery['subtype'] wont do the trick here.

I am trying to fetch data with a GraphQL query and put the response in a state like this:

```
const [departments, setDepartments] = useState<TheTypeINeedToAccess>();

setDepartments(data?.generateOrgChart?.departments);
```

But to do this I need the correct type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with picking the subtypes is the optional properties. If you make the object non-nullish, TypeScript can pick out the subtype.

```js
type Departments = Required<GetCompanyChartQuery>["generateOrgChart"]["departments"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74393523/8662476).

It even works with arrays and optional properties.

```
type DeepPick<T, K extends string> = T extends object ? {
  [P in Head<K> & keyof T]: T[P] extends readonly unknown[] ? DeepPick<T[P][number], Tail<Extract<K, `${P}.${string}`>>>[] : DeepPick<T[P], Tail<Extract<K, `${P}.${string}`>>>
} : T
type Head<T extends string> = T extends `${infer First}.${string}` ? First : T;
type Tail<T extends string> = T extends `${string}.${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never;
```

Usage example:

```
interface TestBook {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface TestUser {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  books: TestBook[];
  book: TestBook,
}

type T = DeepPick<TestUser, "id" | "books.name" | "book.id">;
//T = {
//  id: string;
//  books: {
//    name: string;
//  }[];
//  book: {
//    id: string;
//  };
//}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m36j3N)