# How to implement deep pick in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types

I would like to implement deep pick in typescript.

My example code is:

```
interface TestBook {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
interface TestUser {
    id: string;
    email: string;
    books: TestBook[];
}
```

I and I would like to use deep pick like:

```
const foo: DeepPick<TestUser, 'id' | 'books.name'> = {...
/*

{
  id: ..
  books: [{name: ...}]
}

*/
```

Problem: There is only `Pick` in standard typescript and there is no library implement this `DeepPick`.

How can I do it? Which technic should I use?

I tried to find on google and SO.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/73913130/18244921?

Comment: @caTS Looks like it's a whole other topic

Comment: Why not use something like [ts-deep-pick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-deep-pick)?

Comment: Because its use unstandar way for array `'books.[].id'` but I need to use `books.id`

Comment: I came up with [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq3LQw) mess. If it works for your use case, I can write up an answer.

Comment: Its cool, working!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's first define some utility types to get the "head" or "tail" of a path:

```
type Head<T extends string> = T extends `${infer First}.${string}` ? First : T;

type Tail<T extends string> = T extends `${string}.${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never;
```

Then our DeepPick can take the heads of the paths and then deep pick the tail:

```
type DeepPick<T, K extends string> = T extends object ? {
  [P in Head<K> & keyof T]: T[P] extends readonly unknown[] ? DeepPick<T[P][number], Tail<Extract<K, `${P}.${string}`>>>[] : DeepPick<T[P], Tail<Extract<K, `${P}.${string}`>>>
} : T
```

If it's not an object, we shouldn't do anything to it. Inside the mapped type, I also added a case for arrays.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m36j3N)

Comment: Looks like there is a issue for property starting with same "key" (book vs books) https://tsplay.dev/mppOpm I think that `infer` is problem

Comment: @teteyi3241 I corrected the implementation now

Comment: Wow, Is it magic ?

Comment: Is it possible to have type suggestions like normal Pick?

Comment: @BoomPT Have you tried the answer below?

Comment: This is brilliant. Would you know how to unwrap the final object instead eg: "user.friends.age" to return the type as number[] versus: 
{ 
   user: { 
              friends: [{name: "bob", age: 50}] 
            } 
}
?

Answer (score 1):

I tried @zenly's version and found I was losing type hints, so I've modified it slightly. Here's a more opinionated version (zenly's handles a wider set of inputs) that persisted typehints better

```
type Head<T extends string> = T extends `${infer First}.${string}` ? First : T;
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
type Tail<T extends string> = T extends `${string}.${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never;

type DeepPick<TObject, TKey extends string> = UnionToIntersection<TObject extends object
    ? TKey extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
        ? {
              [P in Head<TKey> & keyof TObject]: DeepPick<TObject[P], Tail<Extract<TKey, `${P}.${string}`>>>;
          }
        : TKey extends keyof TObject
        ? Pick<TObject, TKey>
        : never
    : TObject>;
```

Answer (score 1):

@zelsny answer is amazing, but it fails with arrays that can be null or undefined (`T[] | null | undefined`). This is a solution I found:

```
type DeepPick<T, K extends string> = T extends object
  ? NonNullable<T> extends readonly unknown[]
    ? DeepPick<NonNullable<T>[number], K>[] | Exclude<T, NonNullable<T>>
    : {
        [P in Head<K> & keyof T]: DeepPick<
          T[P],
          Tail<Extract<K, `${P}.${string}`>>
        >
      }
  : T
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gEIHtcDWyA3gLABQyywAJgFzJZSgDmA3BVSHALYQNNWHcgF8KFUJFiIU6LAFUM0Ep2r1GYZiHarufAZqHjKyAEb4CGBnJwWA2gF1hVc4QwB5AA5hgubgBsAfmtMW0JHZzMLDygAOQBXf38QrDxwh2QAH2QQRP9I10t3OLzi%20RAaCBhQCHUbNIJHLJy85viKqpqaYVVCjABJEAxaCC8fPzhk5AAKeos2juqQWoBKCN7oweHK4oSkhlnQhubcpLWnDbctkd3SqHLKpdqDucIT1uz2x67znpNClJhAgAGkuBDGvgCwTQRwsBQst32MNS82yp3yYMR-jKiy6gOOaI%20yC%20nWW3QoYnIFDAAE9PCgACIQCCeAAKwAQBAAPKhgcgANLICAAD0gFQwGi0LAAfMgALxoIWiiDi5C4UwAKwgCDAqkCyFifj2-jgpn8EB5spFYpoEqgEDgND8-hpxJABBAuAA7iBHKoqPqmSz2ZyuYaQMbTebLXZcjxTNAHHz%20dKmtkAKLChD%20eKVHl88ORs0W1DS6X%205AMMgmKi15B2VnUEDIAASDpoXJTyAAZMgCBAabgYGgHAwg2yOdyK3WqKgG0npzPUHBgP4uZnNIgwJ2%20QADAAkxFZIgAdIfBNoRLuy4uqOWa7XKVRrMZafTW%202eUqbRKLzL5Yq1oqrayAHsQoAwMoABiwBQFgp7noYl67sg%20owXBYCVmgr50rIK5rqg37Ab%20SH-gqhFAaqYF-gh4EgJBUDIAASqEV6ocxoRYcsABu0A4e%20hEKuOIZTuQAD0Ym1gAeoEqg2Io0CgiY2QAOR6BAKnGFQql9Ce6macpyAqX0EITP4em8Bpqg6dEWIWXwBnaUZJklEkOLfGS9lWVShnGZsQw3N4kKTF5jnNH5VwBTsrnmfp1nOf52yjDF7mkrUoVaeFhQZb5hSmQEOVORF4IxYVWUIil9y4p5cXkNKQA)