# Typescript: Reduce computational complexity of types

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types, heavy-computation, intersection-types

I am working on a API for a library and I am using types that infer the keys of objects to a string and pick those back based on it. I was able to achieve it thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74390332/how-to-implement-deep-pick-in-typescript) threads, that I used as a starting point. Basically, given the following object

```js
interface Obj {
  prop0: string;
  prop1: {
    prop2: {
      prop3: {prop4: "I am excluded"; prop5: string}[]
    };
    prop6: "I am excluded";
  };
  prop7: "I am excluded";
}
```

I am able to write a function like this

```js
getAttributes(["prop0", "prop1.prop2.prop3[0].prop5"])
```

That returns

```js
{
  prop0: string;
  prop1: {
    prop2: {
      prop3: [{prop5: string}?]
    }
  }
}
```

This is very nice and handy typing to have, BUT it is also very heavy. Using this with more intersections and unions gets to the point that sometimes the Language server crashes/hangs in IDEs (VSCode) and I am working on a relatively powerful machine. I am sure there is something that could be done to slim down those types I am using and get some performance benefit but I don't seem to find a way to do it. Here is what my code looks like:

```js
type Divider<T> = T extends unknown[] ? `[${number}]` : ".";

type Paths<T> = T extends Record<string, unknown>
  ? {[K in keyof T]: `${Exclude<K, symbol>}${"" | `${Divider<T[K]>}${Paths<T[K]>}`}`}[keyof T]
  : T extends (infer X)[]
    ? "" | `${Divider<X>}${Paths<X>}`
    : never;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;

type DeepPick<TObject, TKey extends string> = UnionToIntersection<TObject extends object
  ? TKey extends `${infer Head}.${infer Tail}` | `${infer Head}[${number}].${infer Tail}`
    ? {
      [P in Head & keyof TObject]: TObject[P] extends (infer A)[]
        ? [DeepPick<A, Tail>?]
        : DeepPick<TObject[P], Tail>
    }
    : TKey extends `${infer Head}[${number}]`
      ? {
        [P in Head & keyof TObject]: TObject[P] extends (infer A)[] ? [A?] : never
      }
      : TKey extends keyof TObject
        ? Pick<TObject, TKey>
        : never
  : TObject>;

declare function getAttributes<T, P extends Paths<T>>(attributes: P[]): DeepPick<T, P>;
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgNzgEwgJwDwBUB8UC8UWUEAHsBAHbIDOUArpQNaUD2A7pQNoC6UA-FAAGXACQBvSvQC2AI3QBfHkKgAuKACIAdBoDcAKH2hIUAAoBDYAAsa2PIWJkK1OgCUIAY1ZpkGGsDQ4SgBzABoGZjZOHH0oAShxLgBpKCCoJggQVgAzIh51IQkAUVIPABt6VAwk8JoQOVYynAUJDQ0oAB9hCXgkVEwsZJ5miQtrW0Gk4YUhGYUuDKzcrB5YtSIScipaKAAKIOz0KAANAEpeNbjBNs7u8V6UdAxjkfExm2fmoUv1yggEdAGIzgaAAVUocFYlCwrAAkpQKGgaJ5gJDKBhQfY9qDNs4duZKCB4rsmOpQacCHgEKwUL9-ugKU5tnQSeoDkdYRT8FSach4rC6QC0EDjNAYBAIGBTHAPExsAB5WQAKxR4SwSUyuOZUH8gRCWPBaJh8MRyI8qKhCuVKK1LigrGt5rWgnVmqZdsK4nZaCgAAkIOZkAotBJvURzHAyjNbp6w-7A-MJFI5IoeCGvZRDj6sBGo984lcEj84lxTKlKH6A3yAGTpTI5IiKlXm-KNx3AUt8d07faZo4AQXOqwLI-iXHFkulsow-bVuZw-GHo7i6gnUplcqwTZRnbnkZiI4UP3UrqJ3bosb7PvjQbEkhk8jQSnzo8E4mLBdL5crgagtcWDZbu2rZAc2HamF2Wx2r2WZQIOvBjv2i6CugH5HsuJ4ameUE7AByzbk6y6FlOm4EcAapYQeRHqH8QprCeZE4CKIJQE2BBFnEYBoKwYAAAzqLqQTBAYnHcWAACM6jviOXE8QATFJH6yWAADMUnKQALOoGgCuY0ibOUlQQMgehQMpACsAkBEJ8xLnECgiQWykAGzabp+lkIZqAmY5DlrMpADsblQHpBkVN5ej6Ee+ioOU5hoNA2SMOaaJQMEEDAP2wDWbI9AULYZbnmYlgfE2OA4Lslg5XlEA0Oopi8Kcq4Suu05NuEpgxPoXiUP4IXZYEuX5ex6WZQNcBDbVuxcBoym8Ro4SzWJ4laMpcmrWJKlcLxaYWRoPCnECVWDTVNAbTxvEGMdE2nedEl3etylbTt-B3eZV3jZNZ2BR91X5XdK0ub9J3-cpgNiY9m3bTwr2aUAA).

Consider that the function signature above is heavily simplified. In my actual `getAttributes` function I pass further computed and conditional types to `Paths` and `DeepPick` that I didn't include to avoid making the reading even more complex. I want to add that I am not getting excessive type instantiation or too complex errors. This works, but I can feel (and sometimes see) the compiler struggling with it, with random crashes.

To add some context, this function is actually a method on a database entity, called (approximately) like this `getItem<P extends Paths<Entity>(key: Key<Entity>, attributes?: P[]): DeepPick<Entity, P>`. It retrieves the item from the db, but only with the attributes (if) specified. It doesn't strip them from the item after retrieving but implements an actual specific db functionality that only sends those attributes via the network, reducing the response size.

Comment: What's the point of this?  If I had a `obj` of that type, why wouldn't I just write `obj.prop0` and `obj.prop1.prop2.prop3[0].prop5`?

Comment: I didn't mention nor include what the function does at runtime. If you're interested, the array is a list of attributes to pick when retrieving the object from a db.

Comment: Sometimes typesafety ain't worth it? JS is a language, too. Types reduce but don't eliminate errors. In a non-typesafe language, people write tests for things that would be caught by the compiler in a typesafe language. Don't get me wrong, type safety is very nice to have....until it becomes burdensome, which it sounds like it is. Your function signature also looks like lodash's `get` or `pick` - hard to understand the practical purpose of what you've invented here.

Comment: I added some context information at the end of the post, hope it's clearer now!

Comment: This might be beyond what you can expect to get answered on Stack Overflow.  Right now your example doesn't seem to actually demonstrate the problem, so it's not a [mre].  And if the minimal example that shows the actual problem is very complex, then it's probably something you need one-on-one help with and not the sort of thing that's going to benefit future readers much.  Do you think it's possible to find some relatively small demo of the issue (like, less than a screenful of code) that others can work on to test out any fixes they might suggest?

Comment: Not for Stack Overflow, unfortunately.  We can’t require people to navigate away to get the [mre].

Comment: @jcalz I m going to try and reproduce it in the playground